# Writing .htaccess file in Ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I have a domain `http://www.mydomain.com`.  My root folder structure is like this.

- Root

  -Wordpress

i want to redirect all requests to wordpress folder.
I googled and wrote the file like this

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} http://mydomain.com/ [nc]
rewriterule (.*)$ http://mydomain.com/wordpress [r=301,nc]
```

I am now getting 404 File not found error.
i even tried to use another technique to create an index file and use a `header('location:/wordpress1)`,This works well,but whenever I upload a theme in Wordpress it gives me 500 Internal srver Error..
Anyone who can help me with this
**Note:I am tagging php because they might use this file**

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the document root?  If so, do it properly instead of hackily changing the doc root.

Comment: change the document root mean?At go daddy there is concept of pointing..you can point through this way

Comment: Ah, am not familiar with the setup of godaddy.  As you mentioned Ubutunu, I had assumed it was a server on which you control Apache.

Comment: Every cpanel has a domain central like fatcow,Hostgator.But Godaddy Sucks..I am really very sad after hosting my domain there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond  $0            !^wordpress/
RewriteRule  ^.*$          wordpress/$0
This is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP_HOST variable contains the server name that the client issues the HTTP request to.  In your case mydomain.com.  The current cond will never match.  Rewriting the host and redirecting to a subdirectory are different issues.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

# This will redirect mydomain.com URIs to www.mydomain.com
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mydomain\.com$             [NC]
RewriteRule  ^.*$          http://www.mydomain.com/$0  [R=301,L] 

# This will do an INTERNAL redirect to the wordpress folder
RewriteCond  $0            !^wordpress/
RewriteRule  ^.*$          wordpress/$0
```

The cond on the second rule is to prevent an internal redirect loop.  $0 is set to "the entire match string".

Also remove the index file and location.  It's an invalid syntax and it has all sorts of side-effects for the novice as you have found.

Comment: I've just had a look at the mentor website.  It's a major company, and this post seems to be unrelated to it so I've removed the confusing references.  It doesn't have a wordpress URI.   I also note that the OP variously uses wordpress and wordpress1

Comment: I've just checked your site and the response headers include **Server**: _Microsoft-IIS/7.0_ and **X-Powered-By**: _ASP.NET_.  IIS doesn't use `.htaccess` files.  Have a look at how to configure **web.config** files.  Did you mean to buy an IIS shared service?

Comment: OMG it means that I am using IIS? I want to use php at any cost

Comment: If you want to run PHP then why did you pick an IIS service?  GoDaddy offers a choice of LAMP and IIS options.  It may just be that Godady implements a default 404 redirector to an IIS box, but if I were you I'd first of all comment out all `.ht*` files and create a **phpinfo()** script and execute it, say `http://darinarealtor.com/info.php` and check your config.

Comment: it is supporting php because if i do http://darinarealtor.com/wordpress1,I get the results.How can a IIS server handle a Php request..

Comment: did you do a phpinfo? IIS usually uses fastcgi

Comment: Yup "**System** Windows NT P3NW8SH162 6.0 build 6002".  It's IIS + FastCGI + PHP 5.2.  Looks like you've ordered the wrong service.  Change it or use web.config

Comment: ,It means i can't host my Wordpress site here?

Comment: Siggghhhhh.  Yes you can host WP on IIS, but you need to configure it for WP.  This includes using web.config and not .htaccess to do URI rewriting.

Comment: can you tell me how to write web config file so that all request goes to wordpress1 folder

Comment: I could but there are ~4,000 Qs on using web.config.  Why not try there first before asking your own Q on rewriting URIs under IIS.  This is my last post on the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|wordpress/wp_content)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The second line are exceptions. You may need to add more to include folders that html needs to include.